# PHP _POST['field'] is empty when using API url

Tags: php, rest, api, http, post

I followed the below online tutorial to build a PHP API.

https://trinitytuts.com/restful-web-services-with-php-mysqli/

The HTTP request works perfectly when I use Chrome's "Advanced Rest Client". I get the following response:

```
{
"status": 1
"msg": "Your record inserted successfully"
}
```

[image]

I tried to put the following URL directly into my web browser:

```
http://localhost/API/insert.php/name=paul&email=paul@domain.com&status=active
```

I expected the same result as I received when I used the Advanced Rest Client however, I received the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name
```

I am setting the variable 'name' using the following PHP code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

My understanding is that when I paste the URL into the browser, the $name variable is not set to $_POST['name'] because entering the URL is not actually a post action.

Is it possible for me add a parameter to the URL so as to tell the browser to post? For example:

```
http://localhost/API/insert.php/type=POST&name=paul&email=paul@domain.com&status=active
```

In a nutshell, I want to be able to past a URL directly into a web browser and and not have to post it via a HTML form.

This is my PHP code for insert.php

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$id = 1;

$sql = "INSERT INTO `service`.`user` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `status`) VALUES ($id, '$name', '$email', '$status');";

if ($connection->query($sql)) {
$msg = array("status" =>1 , "msg" => "Your record inserted successfully");
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}

$json = $msg;

header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);


@mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Post is not done through the browser url, $_GET is.  Change `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Comment: localhost/API/insert.php?name=paul&email=paul@domain.com&status=active  <-- notice the ? between url and parameters

Comment: use ? as the begin of the get parameters, not a /

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by changing $_POST to $_GET in insert.php

Comment: But is it really?, you dont want to "post" with a `GET` as thats not RESTful

Comment: Oops.. Typo.. This is fixed now.